# Ubuntu send alert mail if CPU usage continusly heigher than a certain amount

Tags: performance, scripts

I need a way to send alert email if the CPU usage is higher than 80% for more than 5 minute. Installing new software on the server not allowed for me. Is there any way to handle it through a shell script and a scheduled cron job?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the load averages from `uptime` to get the 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages, and have a cron job that runs every minute.

Note that a load average of `1` means that 1 full core (or work equivalent to 1 full core) is being used. That means that if you have 4 cores, the load average you're looking for is 3.20.